# Finding java imports inVSCode with Bazel

Tags: visual-studio-code, bazel

Not sure if this is a Bazel question or VScode question but  probably a bit of both.

I'm new to VSCode and am trying to setup a project using Bazel as my build system if that matters. I'm trying to find a way to get the imports for classes used in my code, but can't seem to get VSCode to resolve them.

I've seen elsewhere that the [Maven for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-maven) plugin should be able to import symbols in my java code, but it doesn't seem to be doing for me. This is why I think there is an issue with using Bazel.

Is there a way to:

1. Resolve the imports for specific symbols (like @Configuration from SpringBoot) automatically?
2. Add those deps to my build file automatically? (I've got the relevent external deps set up correctly in my workspace.)

Any help would be appreciated and if I need to provide more information, please let me know.

Comment: https://github.com/bazelbuild/vscode-bazel/issues/281 tracks this FR.